# Como listar arquivos e pastas do servidor ftp?

Tags: java, android, listview, ftp

Não estou conseguindo fazer a listagem do servidor FTP no app, utilizando o emulador do Android, percebo que nas versões antigas do Android a listagem acontece normalmente.

Porém a partir do Android 4 tenho problemas para isso, também testei rodando o projeto no meu celular que está no Android 6 e também tenho mesmo problema. Só funciona nas versões antigas.

Consigo criar pastas pelo aplicativo normalmente só não consigo listar. Os arquivos e pastas são armazenadas em uma array que são listados num listview em uma Activity são listados pastas e outra arquivos.

Métodos chamados de conexão

```
public boolean Conectar(String Host, String Usuario, String Senha, int Porta) {
    try {
        mFtp = new FTPClient();

        mFtp.connect(Host, Porta);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFtp.getReplyCode())) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Conexão foi feita");
            boolean status = mFtp.login(Usuario, Senha);

            mFtp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            Log.i("STATUS", "CONECTADO");
            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possível conectar " + Host);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Método chamados  de listagem de arquivos e pastas

```
public FTPFile[] Dir(String Diretorio) {
    try {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFtp.listFiles(Diretorio);
        return ftpFiles;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "Erro: não foi possível  listar os   arquivos do diretório "
                        + Diretorio + ". " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

public FTPFile[] DirPasta(String Diretorio) {
    try {
        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFtp.listDirectories(Diretorio);
        return ftpFiles;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possível  listar pastas do diretório "
                + Diretorio + ". " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Método que faz a listagem de pastas

```
    public void ListarPastasdoFTP() {
    Log.i(TESTE, "Entrou no ListarArquivosdoFTP");
    classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
    ClienteFTP.Conectar("31.170.165.237", "meuUsuario", "123", 21);

    FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.DirPasta("/public_html/uploads");
    if (arquivos != null) {
        int length = arquivos.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                Log.i(TESTE, "Entrou no ListarArquivosdoFTP 2");
                ArquivosFTP.add(f.getName());
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ArquivosFTP);
        LvlistarArquivosFTP.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        arquivosArray = ArquivosFTP;

        Log.i(TESTE, "Entrou no ListarArquivosdoFTP 3, ArquivosArray: "
                + arquivosArray);
    }

}
```

Método que faz a listagem de arquivos

```
public void ListarArquivosdoFTP() {
    // Log.i(TESTE, "Entrou no ListarArquivosdoFTP pasta: "+ pasta);
    classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
    ClienteFTP.Conectar("31.170.165.237", "meuUsuario", "123", 21);

    // MainActivity at = new MainActivity();
    // String pasta = at.nomePasta;
    Log.i(TESTE, "Entrou no ListarArquivosdoFTP 1");

    String caminho = "/public_html/uploads";
    String caminhoCompleto = caminho + File.separator + itemClicado;

    Log.i(TESTE, "Caminho Completo: " + caminhoCompleto);

    FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.Dir(caminhoCompleto);
    if (arquivos != null) {
        int length = arquivos.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
            if (f.isFile()) {
                Log.i(TESTE, "Entrou no ListarArquivosdoFTP 2");
                ArquivosFTP.add(f.getName());
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ArquivosFTP);
        LvlistarArquivosFTP.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arquivosArray = ArquivosFTP;
    }

}
```

Gente descobrir o motivo por não está listando, O problema foi tentar inserir uma informação na Thread da interface gráfica dentro de uma outra Thread, fugindo do escopo atual.

E a parte que não executa é exatamente a qual inseri no array para exibir na interface gráfica.

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ArquivosFTP);
        LvlistarArquivosFTP.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arquivosArray = ArquivosFTP;
```

Ai fico na dúvida de como inserir esse arquivos do Array para a Thread para executa na interface gráfica no caso na listview.

Na opinião de vocês qual a melhor classe para resolver esse problema classe Handler, AsyncTask ou outro? Se sim como? Usando a Handle e tentando passa as informações para a Thread os arquivos do array chegavam lá nulos por que não executava o ArrayAdapter. Como resolver nesse contexto?

Qualquer informação, estou a disposição.

Answer (score 2):

Acabei descobrindo que estava com problemas na Thread, onde somente a Thread principal pode alterar as views e para alterar views por outra Thread precisa acessa a Thread principal através do Handler. Estava tentando adicionar itens no layout através do setAdapter por outra Thread. Tipo:

```
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                   //Código para alterar Layout, acessando Thread Principal

                                    });

                    }



                 new Thread() {
                 public void run() {

                 //Código para conexão ao servidor (Por Exemplo), acessando outra Thread

                     }
                 }.start();
```